# Patrón de repositorios no guarda entidad cuando añado lista al automapeo

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

Tengo un proyecto con una conexión de tipo [ADO.NET Entity Data Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrQrI.png) con la opción [Code First from existing database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAnoj.png) .

Estoy tratando de crear un nuevo registo de mi entidad llamada `CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS`. Cuando la creo con el siguiente código en mi modelo `MUsuario` en la capa de negocios, mapeando mi DTO de usuario llamado `DTOUsuario` ,con mi entidad de usuario y luego guardándolo con mi repositorio de usuario en mi unitOfWOrk llamado `UsuarioRepo`, no se guarda nada. No arroja errores, todo parece estar bien, pero el registro no es creado.

PD: a este punto ya he debugeado el mapeo de mi entidad con mi DTO antes de llamar al método save() de mi unitOfWork y se ve bien, contodas sus propiedades, incluyendo la lista de permisos.

```cs
public async Task<DTOUsuario> Guardar(DTOUsuario user)   
{
      bool accion = false;
      crearUsuario(user);
      return user;

}
private void crearUsuario(DTOUsuario user)
{
    CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS usuario = mapper.Map<DTOUsuario,CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS>(user);
    unitOfWork.UsuarioRepo.Create(usuario); 
    unitOfWork.Save();
}
```

Mis repositorios en mi unitOfWork y método save()

```cs
private UsuarioRepo _UsuarioRepo = null;
public UsuarioRepo UsuarioRepo { get { if (this._UsuarioRepo == null) this._UsuarioRepo = new UsuarioRepo(this.context); return this._UsuarioRepo; } }
private Repository<CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES> _PermisosRepo = null;
public Repository<CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES> PermisosRepo { get { if (this._PermisosRepo == null) this._PermisosRepo = new Repository<CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES>(this.context); return this._PermisosRepo; } }

public async Task Save()
{
    try
    {
        await this.context.SaveChangesAsync(sess);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Pero cuando ignoro la lista de permisos desde la lista de propiedades de mi utilidad de automapeo AutoMapperConfiguration , funciona, LA ENTIDAD DE USUARIO ES GUARDADA PERFECTAMENTE ! .

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<DTOUsuario, CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.USU_FECHA_CREACION_USUARIO, act => act.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CLCAR_INSPECCION, act => act.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CLCAR_PERFILES, act => act.Ignore())
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CLCAR_SOLICITUD_INSPECCION, act => act.Ignore());
                //.ForMember(dest => dest.CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES, act => act.Ignore());
```

Esta entidad tiene una lista de permisos, representada por una entidad llamada `CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES`.
`CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS` entidad

```cs
public partial class CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS()
        {
            CLCAR_INSPECCION = new HashSet<CLCAR_INSPECCION>();
            CLCAR_SOLICITUD_INSPECCION = new HashSet<CLCAR_SOLICITUD_INSPECCION>();
            CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES = new HashSet<CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int USU_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string USU_USERNAME { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string USU_NOMBRES { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string USU_APELLIDO_MATERNO { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string USU_CLAVE { get; set; }

        public int USU_PERFIL_ID { get; set; }

        public int? USU_RUT { get; set; }

        [StringLength(1)]
        public string USU_DV { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "date")]
        public DateTime USU_FECHA_CREACION_USUARIO { get; set; }

        public bool USU_ACTIVO { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CLCAR_INSPECCION> CLCAR_INSPECCION { get; set; }

        public virtual CLCAR_PERFILES CLCAR_PERFILES { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CLCAR_SOLICITUD_INSPECCION> CLCAR_SOLICITUD_INSPECCION { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES> CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES { get; set; }
    }
```

Mi DTO de usuario `DTOUsuario` PD: En este DTO cambié la lista de permisos , porque estaba arrojándome un error de conversión de lista de objetos hacia array, cuando la intentaba poblar

```cs
public class DTOUsuario
    {

        public DTOUsuario()
        {
            //CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES = new List<DTOPermisos>();
        }

        public int? USU_ID { get; set; }
        public int? USU_PERFIL_ID { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string USU_USERNAME { get; set; }
        public bool USU_ACTIVO { get; set; }


        //anexo
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string USU_CLAVE { get; set; }

        public int USU_RUT { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(1)]
        public string USU_DV { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(30)]
        public string USU_NOMBRES { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string USU_APELLIDO_MATERNO { get; set; }

        //public List<DTOPermisos> CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES { get; set; }

        public DTOPermisos[] CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES { get; set; }

    }
```

`CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES` entidad

```cs
public partial class CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES()
        {
            CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS = new HashSet<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int PESP_ID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PESP_NOMBRE { get; set; }

        public int PESP_TIPO { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string PESP_DESCRIPCION { get; set; }

        public int PESP_FUN_ID { get; set; }

        public bool PESP_ACTIVO { get; set; }

        public virtual CLCAR_MAE_FUNCIONALIDAD CLCAR_MAE_FUNCIONALIDAD { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS> CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS { get; set; }
    }
```

`DTOPermisos` mi DTO de permisos

```cs
public class DTOPermisos
   {

       public int PESP_ID { get; set; }
       [MaxLength(40)]
       public string PESP_NOMBRE { get; set; }
       public int PESP_TIPO { get; set; }
       [MaxLength(150)]
       public string PESP_DESCRIPCION { get; set; }
       public int? PESP_FUN_ID { get; set; }
       public bool PESP_ACTIVO { get; set; }

       public DTOPermisos[] CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS { get; set; }
       public DTOFuncionalidad CLCAR_MAE_FUNCIONALIDAD { get; set; }

   }
```

ambos tienen una relación de muchos a muchos en mi contexto, representada así:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS>()
                .HasMany(e => e.CLCAR_PERMISOS_ESPECIALES)
                .WithMany(e => e.CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS)
                .Map(m => m.ToTable("CLCAR_USUARIOS_PESPECIALES").MapLeftKey("USU_ID").MapRightKey("PESP_ID"));
```

What should I change? my head is almost exploding, please help !
if you need any further information, i will pay attention and upload this post. Thanks for your attention.

EDICIÓN -------
En respuesta al comentario de leandro. Dentro de mi `UoW` cambié mi repositorio de usuario(el cual estaba ya creado. Estoy reutilizando, puesto que es un proyecto existente que estoy modificando), por un repositorio general, pero tampoco me grabó.

Lo comentado es como lo tenía antes

```cs
//private UsuarioRepo _UsuarioRepo = null;
//public UsuarioRepo UsuarioRepo { get { if (this._UsuarioRepo == null) this._UsuarioRepo = new UsuarioRepo(this.context); return this._UsuarioRepo; } }
private Repository<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS> _UsuarioRepo = null;
public Repository<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS> UsuarioRepo { get { if (this._UsuarioRepo == null) this._UsuarioRepo = new UsuarioRepo(this.context); return this._UsuarioRepo; } }
```

Acá muestro cómo instancio mi contexto y creo mi método `SaveChangesAsync` , el cual llama al método `Auditar`, pero no creo que ese método influya en el grabado, puesto que se guarda en el return

```cs
public ClicarContext() : base("name=ClicarContext")
{
    Database.SetInitializer<BaseDbContext>(null);
}
public Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(DTOSessionUsuario _sess)
{
   Auditar(_sess);
   return base.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private void Auditar(DTOSessionUsuario _sess)
{
   var modifiedEntries = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.Entity is IAuditable && (x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added
             || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified || x.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted));

   foreach (var entry in modifiedEntries)
   {
       IAuditable entity = entry.Entity as IAuditable;
       if (entity != null)
       {

          Log log = new Log()
          {
              USU_ID = (int)_sess.Usuario.USU_ID,
              LOG_FECHA = DateTime.Now,
              LOG_LLAMADA = _sess.llamada,
              LOG_OPERACION = (entry.State == EntityState.Added) ? "insercion" : ((entry.State == EntityState.Modified) ? "modificacion" : "eliminacion"),
              LOG_DATOS = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry.Entity, Formatting.Indented)
          };

              this.Set<Log>().Add(log);

           }
      }

 }
```

Así instancio mi contexto dentro de mi `UoW`, el cual es utilizado para todas las operaciones, como se puede ver más arriba en mis ejemplos de código.

```cs
private readonly ClicarContext context;
```

Acá les muestro mi `UsuarioRepo`

```cs
public class UsuarioRepo : Repository<CLCAR_MAE_USUARIOS>
    {

        protected readonly DbContext _context;

        public UsuarioRepo(DbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public DTOUsuario UsuarioInsert(DTOUsuario user)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> parametros = new List<SqlParameter>();

            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("PERF_ID", (user.USU_PERFIL_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_PERFIL_ID));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_USERNAME", (user.USU_USERNAME == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_USERNAME));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_CLAVE", (user.USU_CLAVE == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_CLAVE));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_VIGENTE", (user.USU_ACTIVO == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_ACTIVO));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_RUT", (user.USU_RUT == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_RUT));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_DV", (user.USU_DV == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_DV));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_NOMBRES", (user.USU_NOMBRES == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_NOMBRES));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_PATERNO", (user.USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_APELLIDO_PATERNO));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_MATERNO", (user.USU_APELLIDO_MATERNO == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_APELLIDO_MATERNO));

            return _context.Database.SqlQuery<DTOUsuario>("USUARIO_INSERT @PERF_ID, @USU_USERNAME, @USU_CLAVE, @USU_VIGENTE, @USU_VIGENTE,@USU_RUT,@USU_DV,@USU_NOMBRES,@USU_PATERNO,@USU_MATERNO",
                parametros.ToArray()).FirstOrDefault();

        }

        public bool UsuarioUpdate(DTOUsuario user)
        {
            //List<SqlParameter> parametros = new List<SqlParameter>();

            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_ID", (user.USU_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_ID));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("PERF_ID", (user.PERF_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.PERF_ID));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("TR_ID", (user.TR_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.TR_ID));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_USERNAME", (user.USU_USERNAME == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_USERNAME));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_CLAVE", (user.USU_PASS == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_PASS));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_VIGENTE", (user.USU_VIGENTE == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_VIGENTE));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("TIP_USU", (user.TIP_USU == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.TIP_USU));

            //List<DTOUsuario> datos = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DTOUsuario>("USUARIO_UPDATE @USU_ID, @PERF_ID, @TR_ID, @USU_USERNAME, @USU_CLAVE, @USU_VIGENTE, @TIP_USU",
            //    parametros.ToArray()).ToList();

            return true;

        }

        public List<DTOUsuario> UsuarioSelect(DTOUsuario user)
        {
            List<SqlParameter> parametros = new List<SqlParameter>();

            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_ID", (user.USU_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_ID));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("PERF_ID", (user.PERF_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.PERF_ID));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("TR_ID", (user.TR_ID == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.TR_ID));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_USERNAME", (user.USU_USERNAME == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_USERNAME));
            parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_CLAVE", (user.USU_CLAVE == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_CLAVE));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("USU_VIGENTE", (user.USU_VIGENTE == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.USU_VIGENTE));
            //parametros.Add(new SqlParameter("TIP_USU", (user.TIP_USU == null) ? DBNull.Value : (object)user.TIP_USU));

            List<DTOUsuario> datos = _context.Database.SqlQuery<DTOUsuario>("USUARIO_SELECT @USU_USERNAME, @USU_CLAVE",
                parametros.ToArray()).ToList();

            return datos;

        }


    }
```

Comment: una duda, como haces desde el `save()` del `UoW` para invocar los save de los diferentes `repos` ? porque cuando agrgas la entidad lo haces al `UsuarioRepo` pero despues usas `context.SaveChangesAsync()`, salvo que el `UoW` y los repos usen la misma intancia del `context`, pero no nos muestras ese context como se instancia y si es unico para todas las operaciones que realizas

Comment: @LeandroTuttini viendo tu comentario, me hizo lógica y cambié mi UsuarioRepo(estoy tomando como base otro proyecto por eso intento reutilizar algo de código y este repo venía creado), por un repositorio general, ahora agrego la edición en el post